# My site is still showing http as i have already migrated from http to https

Tags: https, google-search-console, http-error

My question is how to remove the HTTP error in Google Search Console, As I have already migrated from HTTP to HTTPS, but still showing error of HTTP in search console. My website is https:/www.clinvigilant.com

Can anyone guide me in that, As it would be great help for me

I need permanent solution of HTTP error from Google Search Console.

Comment: If you're using a url-prefix property, did you create a new one for the HTTPS version? or if you're using a domain property, did you set up a 301 redirect from http -> https?

Comment: yes we have use that still showing the error.